# Determining if a directory already exists using SVN ANT

Tags: svn, ant

I'm looking to create a directory using SVN ANT, but only so if the directory does not already exist (using the `mkdir` nested task with SVN ANT appears to fail if you specify a directory that already exists).

Is there a isExists flag or something of that ilk that I can use here?  Or something else I can use to detect existing directories on an SVN repository before I continue with creating my directories via an ANT script?

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Stuart

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [`svnExists` condition](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/conditions.html). This allows you to do something like (Using ant-contrib)

```
<if>
    <not><svnExists target="..."/></not>
    <then>
        <svn>
            <mkdir url="..." message="Creating a directory" />
        </svn>
    </then>
</if>
```

Note: all the intermediate directories must already exist when using `mkdir`.

Comment: Oops, seems to be top-level now: http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/conditions.html#svnexists

Answer (score 0):

The [available](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html) task enables you to set a property dependent on the existence of a file or directory

```
<available property="desired-dir-exists" file="src/desired_dir"/>

<target name="mkdir" unless="desired-dir-exists">
    <svn>
        <mkdir path="src/desired_dir"/>
    </svn>
</target>
```

Comment: He's referring to the SvnAnt task, not "plain ant"

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. You can set the `failonerror` attribute to `false`. This way if the directory exists, an error message will be printed but the build will not be aborted.

   ```
   <svn failonerror="false">
       <mkdir path="..." message="..."/>
   </svn>
   ```
2. If you want to avoid the error message you will probably need to do something more elaborate, such as performing a checkout / update first, then examine your working copy to see if the directory you want to create already exists.

Comment: OK thanks for feedback guys, I'll give your suggestions a try.